# insert product programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to insert test product into database with the following code -

```
    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");
            $product
            ->setStoreId(0) 
            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) 
            ->setAttributeSetId(9) 
            ->setTypeId('simple') 
            ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) 
            ->setSku('82394444')
            ->setName('product21')
            ->setWeight(4.0000)
            ->setStatus(1)
            ->setTaxClassId(4)
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
            ->setManufacturer(28)
            ->setColor(24)
            ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014')
            ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2016')
            ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF')            
            ->setPrice(11.22)
            ->setCost(22.33)
            ->setSpecialPrice(00.44)
            ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2015')
            ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2016')
            ->setMsrpEnabled(1)
            ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1)
            ->setMsrp(99.99)            
            ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
            ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
            ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')            
            ->setDescription('This is a long description')
            ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')

            ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()))
            ->addImageToMediaGallery('media/catalog/product/1/0/10243-1.png', array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false)

            ->setStockData(array(
                               'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                               'manage_stock'=>1,
                               'min_sale_qty'=>1,
                               'max_sale_qty'=>2,
                               'is_in_stock' => 1,
                               'qty' => 999
                           )
            )

            ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 7)); 
            $product->save();
```

But when I run this code, product does not appears in product list. I checked the database catalog tables, I found that `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table stores wrong value in `value` field. It inserts each time value like `-5.html, -6.html` when I run the code. Is that the reason for not showing product in admin grid or in frontend?

Any comments appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You reindexed data and cleared the cache after adding your products? If not, pls try because you description seems to me like the products are there but you just cant see them.

Comment: I have already disabled cache and index management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing attribute id 9 with 4, resolves the problem.

```
$product->setAttributeSetId(4)
```